# Algorithm Improvement - element differences in list

Tags: python, algorithm

The task is, you have an array of *n* numbers called `nums`, and an array of *m* numbers called `maxes`.

For each element in `maxes`, find how many members of `nums` are smaller than or equal to that element.

---

#### Example

```
nums = [4, 2, 5, 10, 8]
maxes = [3, 1, 7, 8]

output = [1, 0, 3, 4]
```

The first element, 3, in `maxes`, is higher than only `2` in `nums`, hence the first element in output is 1.

---

The initial solution I could think of was trivial, and it scales as O(n²):

```
def sol_naive(nums,maxes):
    output = []
    for entry in maxes:
        higher_numbers = len([x for x in nums if x <= entry])
        output.append(higher_numbers)
    return output
```

I'm wondering if there's a better approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple observation is that this problem gets much easier if you sort nums `O(n log(n)`. Then you can use `bisect_left` which uses binary search to find where an element would go in a sorted list and is `O(log(n))` for each element in m. This yields a total time of `O((n+m) log(n))`

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def sol_sorted(nums,maxes):
    output = []
    nums.sort()
    for m in maxes:
        ind = bisect_left(nums, m)
        output.append(len(nums) - ind)
    return output
```

Comment: You might be able to do this slightly faster involving sorting `maxes`, but then you have to futz around a bunch with keeping output ordering, and id didn't seem worth it to me.

Comment: Very nice! thank you for making me a little smarter today

Comment: If you sort `maxes` as well, you can get your time to `O(n log(n) + m log(m))` , which benefits us the larger the length difference is between `n` & `m`. so if you want to do `len(n) == 10000`, `len(m)  == 10`, it makes more sense to sort each once and then essentially use the combine step of merge-sort to find the indexes all in one go (at `O(n + m)`), as opposed to doing separate bisections for each max.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was saying. The downside is that you have to keep track of the original order of `maxes` so output ends up in the right order. It's not algorithmically slower, but it requires more python, and adds a fair amount of overhead. I would be interested to see if it ever ends up faster in practice.

Comment: The base idea looks solid. Using `bisect_left()` instead of `bisect_right()` ruins it, as does subtracting the index found from the length of `nums`.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your `for-loop` into a `list comprehension`:

```
nums = [4, 2, 5, 10, 8]
maxes = [3, 1, 7, 8]
output = [len([x for x in nums if x <= entry]) for entry in maxes]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two promising alternatives to ordering `nums` and finding the index of the smallest element therein larger than each element of `maxes`:

**order `maxes`** (ascendingly) and
**tally elements `num in nums`** (`ordered[m-1] <`)
  **`num <= ordered[m]`** and accumulate (finally reordering output) -
O((n+m) log(m))

**order both and take turns finding, for an element in one sequence, the first exceeding it in the other, continuing with the successor thereof**
Looks promising with `len(nums)` and `len(maxes)` in the same ballpark.

---

finger exercise:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def oscar(nums, maxes):
    """ Return an iterable containing for each element m in maxes 
    the number of elements in nums no larger than m. """
    ordered = sorted(nums)
    return (bisect_right(ordered, m) for m in maxes)

# for a list, I'd have to decide whether to make it immutable - and how
_empty = ()

# tries to reduce the ranges searched
def smith(nums, maxes):
    """ Return an iterable containing for each element m in maxes 
    the number of elements in nums no larger than m. """
    if not maxes or not nums:
        return _empty
    output = list()
    ordered = sorted(nums)
    previous = ordered[0]
    index = bisect_right(nums, previous)
    for m in maxes:
        if previous < m:
            index = bisect_right(nums, m, index)
        elif m < previous:
            index = bisect_right(nums, m, 0, index)
        output.append(index)
        previous = m
    return output
```